# How to keep history of data changes in excel for examination

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work in a manufacturing plant and we are trying to keep track of how often we are replacing parts on specific sub-assemblies. Each sub-assembly contains multiple parts that are not changed at the same times. The sheet currently contains the list of parts in one column and their dates of last replacement in the next column. As the date of last replacement is updated, we'd like to have a way to store all the prior dates of replacement for each part.

So essentially, we're trying to keep a sheet that will show each part's date of last replacement as well as have all the prior dates that is was replaced. The past dates can either be stored in the same sheet or in a separate sheet.

Any help would be appreciated. I do not have much of a background in coding.

Comment: It appears that you are asking us to provide you with a full solution. This isn't really what SU is for. Please let us know what you have tried, where it has worked/failed, what your research has shown you already. Use the EDIT button to add this any other relevant information to the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

> The sheet currently contains the list of parts in one column and their dates of last replacement in the next column.

**The most simple method:**
Place the cursor on the "last change date" for a replaced part, then do

1. Insert Cell (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>),
2. select "Shift Cells Right"...
3. and type in the new date.

End result: The earlier date(s) remain to the right of the latest date.